# Showing that $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(y/t)$ is separable by using substitution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Show that $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(y/t)$ is equal to $t\frac{dv}{dt}+v=f(v)$, (which is a separable differential equation) by using substitution of $y = t \cdot v$ or $v =\frac{y}{t}$.

I did the following:

By using the chain-rule, we can write down $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dv} \cdot\frac{dv}{dt}$. The first part of this product, $\frac{dy}{dv}$ is equal to $t$, as $y=t \cdot v$. Using substitution, we can also see that $f(y/t)=f(v)$. Thus, we have found the following equation:
$ t\cdot\frac{dv}{dt} = f(v)$.

My question is what I did wrong, what did I do to lose the '$+ v$' part of the equation?

Thanks for your help,

K. Kamal

---

If anyone is still interested, I forgot that v is a function of t and therefore we need to use the product rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $y = t v$ you can use the Product Rule:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dt}{dt} v + t \dfrac{dv}{dt} = v + t \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dy}{dv}$ is equal to $t$, as $y=t \cdot v\quad$ is wrong.

$y=t \cdot v \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dv}=v\frac{dt}{dv}+t\frac{dv}{dv}=v\frac{dt}{dv}+t\quad$ which is not equal to $t$.

Anyways, this is not the right track.

Change of function $\quad y(t)=t \cdot v(t) \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=v+t\frac{dv}{dt}$